# Deleting a Pricebook Entry using Process Builder that invokes an Apex Class

Tags: apex, class, invocable-method, pricebookentry

apologies if i'm wording this incorrectly, i'm not a developer! I want to delete a pricebook entry if a checkbox is checked on the product object, I'm using process builder to determine the records beforehand, then use apex to delete the child pricebook entry record.

Below is the code that I've written and it's not working saying there is an unexpected token '[' on line 7,

```
public class DeletePricebookEntry

{
        @invocableMethod

        public static void PricebookEntryDelete(List<Id> PricebookEntryIds)

{

            List<PricebookEntry> PricebookEntries =[SELECT id from    PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id in : PricebookEntryIds
                                                   and [product2].create_pricebook__c = 'False'];
        delete PricebookEntries;
        }    
}
```

Comment: Can you check using following query, Select Id, Product2Id from PriceBookEntry where Product2.Create_Pricebook__c = False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code,

```
public class DeletePricebookEntry{
    @invocableMethod
    public static void PricebookEntryDelete(List<Id> PricebookEntryIds){
        List<PricebookEntry> PricebookEntries = [SELECT id from PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id in : PricebookEntryIds and Product2.create_pricebook__c = False];
        if(!PricebookEntries.isEmpty()){
            delete PricebookEntries;
        }
    }    
}
```

1. You can link reference fields using Product2.CustomField__c.
2. You need to remove quotation mark from False, as create_pricebook__c is Checkbox field and it will expect boolean variable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, that works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code for deleting the Pricebooks,

```
public class DeletePricebookEntry{
        @invocableMethod
        public static void PricebookEntryDelete(List<Id> PricebookEntryIds){
        List<PricebookEntry> PricebookEntries =[SELECT id from PricebookEntry WHERE Product2Id IN : PricebookEntryIds and Product2.create_pricebook__c = False];
        if(PricebookEntries.size()>0)
             delete PricebookEntries;
        }    
}
```

Here we are checking if list size is not empty.